# Create Filter to format Date in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have created one setting in my application to select Date Format.So what ever format selected from settings, it will be same throughout the application.

I am thinking to first store the Date format in Database and then set it in to localstorage (As My application is SPA which has different front and back end server.)

So after getting from localstorage , how can i apply the format to each place where dates used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular default date filter

```
$scope.pageDate = new Date();  // Date
$scope.dateFormat = 'dd MMM yyyy, hh:mm a, EEEE';  // Your required format or you can get the value from localstorage
```

Display HTML

```
{{pageDate | date: dateFormat}}
```

It will work

Live demo : https://jsbin.com/lodofum/2/edit?html,js,output